# CGAL: Delaunay triangulation vs triangulation in CGAL's example

Tags: cgal, triangulation, voronoi, delaunay

In my work, I need to obtain first shell of Voronoi neighbors for a focal particle. For this I use Delaunay triangulation which is the dual graph of Voronoi tessellation. The Version of CGAL which I use is 4.7. I always used the basic code in CGAL manual_4.7 as a template to create Delaunay triangulation. My problem is with the headers and typedefs in that example, because I recently discovered they are different from CGAL 4.14 which is the latest version available. In [CGAL 4.7](https://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/Periodic_2_triangulation_2_2p2t2_info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2_8cpp-example.html):

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_2_triangulation_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <vector>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel         K;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_triangulation_traits_2<K>                  Gt;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, Gt>   Vb;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_triangulation_face_base_2<Gt>              Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb>                 Tds;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds>          Delaunay;
typedef Delaunay::Point                                             Point;
```

and in [CGAL 4.14](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/Periodic_2_triangulation_2_2p2t2_info_insert_with_pair_iterator_2_8cpp-example.html):

```
#include <CGAL/Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_traits_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_2_triangulation_face_base_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Periodic_2_triangulation_vertex_base_2.h>
#include <CGAL/Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel             K;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_traits_2<K>             Gt;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_triangulation_vertex_base_2<Gt>                Vbb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_with_info_2<unsigned, Gt, Vbb>  Vb;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_triangulation_face_base_2<Gt>                  Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb>                    Tds;
typedef CGAL::Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_2<Gt, Tds>              Delaunay;
typedef Delaunay::Point                                                 Point;
```

then I double checked the manual to see if the explantions are different or not. As far as I understand, [Software Design 4.14](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/index.html#P2Triangulation2secTraits) and [Software Design 4.7](https://doc.cgal.org/4.7/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/index.html#title5) are the same and match to second example. Since I need triangulation with empty circle property, and I just need to retrieve the indices of neighboring vertices in Delaunay triangulation, does the first also lead to the same results? 
I can check them for some points, but I just doubt that if they produce the same results for every set of points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This leads to exactly the same results.

For a more detailed explanation: the periodic triangulation expects a triangulation data structure with vertices and faces that provide a certain number of functions and members, described by concepts (see [P2T2 concepts](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Periodic_2_triangulation_2/group__PkgPeriodic2Triangulation2Concepts.html)). In CGAL 4.7, the vertex and face classes did not meet these requirements: they were missing some periodic information that is only used in a few functions of P2T2. However everything compiled and ran just fine because the examples did not call these few functions. Some more recent compilers were over-zealous and decided they wanted to be able to compile all functions of the class, even if those that were not called, and thus the vertex and base classes that were being used were not satisfying anymore.

See also https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3624.

Comment: Thank you. So, you mean that there is also no difference between using Periodic_2_Delaunay_triangulation_traits_2 and Periodic_2_triangulation_traits_2, both produce Delaunay triangulation?

Comment: Sorry, I only now realize that the traits also have been changed. This was just another cleaning fix and there is no behavior change. In more detail again: previously, some traits functions required by the Delaunay triangulation concept were actually implemented in the non-Delauany triangulation traits, which meant you could use those non-Delaunay traits and it would work fine. I re-organized it so you are forced to use the proper (Delaunay) traits when you are using a Delaunay triangulation. This was done in https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/2369.